# mysql_num_rows to php data object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am confused in converting my code from mysql * to php data objects. i have an album with a photos in it and i want the first photo of that certain album to be the cover image of the album. i know how to do it in my sql but i am now encountering problems with pdo. here is my code:

```
        $sqlAlb="Select album_id,album_name from albums";
        $resAlb=$db->prepare($sqlAlb);
        $resAlb->execute();
        $strAlb="";
            while($rowAlb = $resAlb->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $rs=$db->prepare("select COUNT(*) from gallery where album_id=".$rowAlb['album_id']);
            $rs->execute();
            $num_rows=$rs->fetchColumn();
            $dset=$rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($rs!=0){
            $strAlb.="<article class='one-third column' data-categories='sermons people'>";
            $strAlb.="<div class='project-thumb'><div class='bordered'>";
            $strAlb.="<figure class='add-border'>";
            $strAlb.="<a class='single-image picture-icon' rel='gallery' ><img src='uploads/photos/".$dset['pic_img']."' alt='' /></a>";
            $strAlb.="</figure>";
            $strAlb.="</div></div></article>";
            }
            }
                echo $strAlb;
```

Comment: Since you're using PDO, which is great, be absolutely sure to use [SQL placeholders](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for all of your user data. `$rowAlb['album_id']` should **never** appear directly inside a query string.

Comment: What problems are you encountering?

Comment: Don't do separate queries in your loop, combine the two queries with a join: `select a.album_id album_id, album_name, count(*) ct from albums a join gallery using (album_id) group by album_id, album_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You were not specific about what problems you were encountering, but my guess is that you are just not getting the data you want from your query.  It appears you are querying for a count value and then trying to use the value as part of the image's href attribute which will likely not work unless your images are numbered in a very specific way.

Personally I would add a specific tintyint (boolean-like) field in your gallery to specifically indicate which image is cover image rather than relying on some sort order which may not be guaranteed based on how you query the table.  I would then utilize a single query joining the album and gallery tables to get teh information you need, something like this:

```
SELECT a.album_id, a.album_name, g.image_filename  <-- or whatever your filename field is
FROM albums AS a
INNER JOIN gallery AS g ON a.album_id = g.album.id
WHERE g.is_cover = 1
```

You can then get all the data you need in a single query rather than 1+ number of albums queries.  You would then iterate through the result set to get at the data you need.